# Logcat CordovaLog not working after update cordova 5

Tags: android, cordova, logcat

after updated the cordova for the new version 5, the logcat stopped working. 
I use a macbook, and I am using this command by command line to enable logcat:

```
adb logcat Cordova:D *:S
```

It is only on this screen is message:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

I'm using the emulator version 4 of Android.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the option "Debugging" is enabled on the smartphone/tablet, then plug it, and try only `adb logcat` on `cmd`. It works for me.

Comment: I see where if is active?

Comment: @Crazy, I did not understand you told.

Comment: how active mode debugging in my emulator?